# Download file from SFTP server with libssh and write it to ofstream by using C++?

Tags: c++, sftp, libssh

I wrote the following code from [this](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_sftp.html).

```
#define MAX_XFER_BUF_SIZE 16384
int main()
{
    char buffer[MAX_XFER_BUF_SIZE];

      //..some content
     access_type = O_RDONLY;
     sftp_file file = sftp_open(sftp, "/home/ra/Desktop/sami/s.txt", access_type, 0);
     ofstream fin("C:/Users/s.txt", ios::binary | ios::in | std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

     nbytes = sftp_read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
     fin.write(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

But the buffer maximum size is predefined. So it only works for small files. I want to get the SFTP file size which size is much bigger. For that I need to send the data as chunks by append mode.

---

```
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(buffer);i++)
{
    fin.write(buffer, buffer[i]);
}
```

I went through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691520/how-to-copy-a-file-in-c-c-with-libssh-and-sftp?rq=1), but i'm stuck in this > How can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed the loop that is in the [Reading a file from the remote computer](https://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_sftp.html#sftp_read) example.

Return it back. The important part of the example modified to use `ofstream` is like:

```
char buffer[MAX_XFER_BUF_SIZE];

// ...

for (;;)
{
    nbytes = sftp_read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (nbytes == 0)
    {
        break; // EOF
    }
    else if (nbytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading file: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
        sftp_close(file);
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }

    fin.write(buffer, nbytes);
    if (!fin)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing");
        sftp_close(file);
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }
}

fin.close();
if (!fin)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error writing");
    sftp_close(file);
    return SSH_ERROR;
}
```

---

*Imo, `fin` seems like a bad name to me. Shouldn't it be `fout` ("file **output**")?*